# problema con un crud de c++ y mysql 0x00007FF91A7035D6 (libmysql.dll)

Tags: mysql, c++, crud, librería

tengo un error de ejecucion el cual no tengo mucha idea de como solucionar ya que intento hacer que me busque dentro de la base de datos pero el me muestra un error de acceso el cual no se como podría llegar a solucionar di alguien me pudiera ayudar se los agradecería mucho de ante mano muchas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] gracias

```cpp
int tablas::buscar() {
    conexion cn = conexion();
    MYSQL_ROW fila;
    MYSQL_RES* resultado;
    if (cn.getconexion()) {
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre de la persona que desea buscar" << endl;
        cin >> nombre;
        string buscar = "select *from clientes where nombres ='%"+nombre+"%'";
        const char* i = buscar.c_str();
        q_estado = mysql_query(cn.getconexion(), i);
        if (!q_estado) {
            resultado = mysql_store_result(cn.getconexion());
            cout << "Los datos son:" << endl;
            cout << "Nombre" << " " << "Apellido" << " " << "Nit" << " " << "genero" << " " << "Telefono" << " " << "correo" << endl;
            while (fila = mysql_fetch_row(resultado)) {
                cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                cout << fila[0] << fila[1] << fila[2] << fila[3] << fila[4] << fila[5] << endl;
            }   
            
        }
        else {
            cout << "no se encontro nada en la busqueda" << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

para las personas que buscan ayuda relacionada a este problema el problema radica en la conexion ala Base de datos